# Does $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ln\left(e^{-x^{2}}+1\right)dx=\frac{3\pi}{4}-1$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

[According to WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5Bln%5C%2840%29Power%5Be%2C-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5D%2B1%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bx%2C-%E2%88%9E%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D), it is equal to approximately $1.35619$ and $\frac{3\pi}{4}-1\approx1.3561944901$.

The integral seems way too difficult for me but I know of the possibly related integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}$ or the other possibly related integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\left(e^{-x}+1\right)dx=\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}$. I've tried u-subs and integration by parts and have come to dead ends with both. How do I solve this integral?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The actual value is close to but different from $\frac{3\pi}{4}-1$. Integration by parts and [$(25.5.3)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.5.E3) give
\begin{align*}
\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\log (1 + {\rm e}^{ - x^2 } ){\rm d}x} & = 2\int_0^{ + \infty } {\log (1 + {\rm e}^{ - x^2 } ){\rm d}x} \mathop  = \limits^{{\rm IBP}} 4\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{x^2 }}{{{\rm e}^{x^2 }  + 1}}{\rm d}x}  \\ &\!\mathop = \limits^{t = x^2 } 2\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\sqrt t }}{{{\rm e}^t  + 1}}{\rm d}t}
 = (2 - \sqrt 2 )\Gamma\! \left( {\tfrac{3}{2}} \right)\!\zeta\! \left( {\tfrac{3}{2}} \right) = 1.3561877903 \ldots 
\end{align*}

Comment: can you tell how did in the last step the integral became $(2-\sqrt2)$...,Is it some named result or something.

Comment: It is said that one uses (25.5.3).

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \ln \left(1 + e^{-x^2}\right)\mathrm d x &= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-nx^2}\mathrm dx\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{\pi} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n\sqrt n}\\
&= \sqrt{\pi} \eta\left(\frac32\right)
\end{align}

Where $\eta$ is the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function).

Answer (score 2):

By integration by parts and infinite series, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
I&= 2\left[x \ln \left(e^{-x^2}+1\right)\right]_0^{\infty}-2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x \cdot(-2 x) e^{-x^2}}{e^{-x^2}+1} d x\\&= 4 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2 e^{-x^2}}{e^{-x^2}+1} d x \\
& =4 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1} \int_0^{\infty} x^2 e^{-n x^2} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
Via integration by parts again on the last integral, we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} x^2 e^{-n x^2} d x 
= & -\frac{1}{2 n} \int_0^{\infty} x d\left(e^{-n x^2}\right) \\
= & \frac{1}{2 n} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-(\sqrt{n} x)^2} d x \\= & \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4 n^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{aligned}
$$
We can now conclude that
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\sqrt{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}} \\
& =\sqrt{\pi} \eta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) \\ OR
& =\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}(\sqrt{2}-2) \zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Where $\eta$ is the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) and $\zeta$ is the [Zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).